# How to perform a javascript action right after redirect?

Tags: javascript, .net, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After a user creates an account on my website, I want to redirect the user to the home page and display a twitter style message bar on top.  This is how I have it:

```
success: function (response) {
            if (response.Success) {
                location.href = response.ReturnUrl;
            } 

            ShowMessageBar(response.Message);                
        },
```

The message bar does appear but it gets displayed only for a second as it gets canceled by the redirect.  What can I do to display the message right after the redirect has completed?  Is there a complete event for the location.href?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will need the Cookie plugin for jQuery:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Put this somewhere in the header of your homepage:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
  if($.cookie("message")) {
    ShowMessageBar($.cookie("message"));
    $.cookie("message", "any_value", { expires: -1 });
});
```

And in your success function:

```
success: function (response) {
        if (response.Success) {
            $.cookie("message", response.Message);
            location.href = response.ReturnUrl;
        } 
    },
```

Comment: I'll need to delete the cookie once the message bar has been displayed right?

Comment: The $.cookie("message", null) doesn't seem to delete it. The message keeps appearing on each reload of the page.  Am I missing something?

Comment: This seems to delete it: $.cookie("message", "any_value", { expires: -1 });

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass it through a `cookie`, the `quesrystring`, or `localStorage`.
Something like this using localStorage or cookies (localStorage is available in IE8+ and most other browsers):

on the current page:

```
if('localStorage' in window) 
    localStorage.setItem('message', response.Message);
else // use cookie
```

On the new page:

```
$(function(){
    if('localStorage' in window && !!localStorage['message']) {
         ShowMessageBar(localStorage['message']);
         localStorage.removeItem('message');
    }
    else // use cookie
});
```

If you are uncomfortable with these techniques there are jquery plugins that wrap this functionality. I would recommend [jstorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).

Comment: Can I then remove the message from the url once the messagebar is shown so it's not displayed all the time?

Comment: If you do not want it to be seen I'd suggest using localStorage, or a cookie. I'll update my post

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I ended up using Sebastian's version this time which seems to do the trick.  Will have to try yours after reading up on localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

Once the url of a page changes all execution stops and is transferred to the new page. Pass a parameter to the new page that triggers the event you want instead.

Comment: I tried this by passing a query string parameter ?newUserMsg but the problem is that the message would display each time the user refreshes after the new loads with the query string.  Is there a way to remove the querystring from the url immediately after using it to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you would need to call ShowMessageBar() from the redirected URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a parameter and check for its existence on document ready.  Probably the easiest way of achieving the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY wanted to show the message, you could always throw it in an alert before you redirect them, which would halt execution until they clicked 'ok'.

Comment: There's always alert :-) But I need to show it on my custom message bar.  Thanks.